# UITableView background issue when upgrade iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicolor

I am using `UITableView` without setting any background color but when I upgrade from iOS6 to iOS7 I found that `UITableView` misbehaves. The problem is its background color.

Comment: What is exactly the misbehavior?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the tableview background color as below

```
tableView.backgroundView = nil; 
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

In iOS7 UITableView default background color is clearColor. So you can change it as following way by adding in viewDidLoad method :

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
```

Here is the good reference

[UITableViewCell show white background and cannot be modified on iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18878258/uitableviewcell-show-white-background-and-cannot-be-modified-on-ios7)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set its background color after the table view becomes visible.