# iOS Tableviewcell separators looks weird

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios7.1

I am using `UITabelViewController` and static cells in `iOS 7.1`. I am seeing desired separator in the `storyboard`, but not in the `simulator`. This drives me crazy.

**Storyboard Screenshot**

[image]

**Simulator Screenshot**

[image]

**I don't want the extra white line before the `separator inset`. But I still need the separator just like the way it is showing in Storyboard Screenshot.** How to remove that extra white line? Any help would be appreciated.

I set the black color for `tableView` background. Still no improvement. Cells are static and are custom cells.

Comment: Do you mean that you want remove the separator line ? Try it `_tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone ;`

Comment: Desired output is Storyboard screenshot..

Comment: Have you set the separator color ?

Comment: Without setting the color, how can I see the color in storyboard? could you please see the screenshots well?

Comment: Yes, I can see the screenshots. I wonder why the separator color in Storyboard Screenshot is not the default color if you didn't set it ? Is it your background image ?

Comment: Hey @KudoCC, Yes. I set the separator color to a golden color. So it is showing color. It is UITableViewController. You cannot set the background image for a tableviewcontroller especially in storyboard. Is that clear?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51393/discussion-between-kudocc-and-dinesh-raja)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for other answers here. I found out what causes the bug.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}
```

Here it is the bug described which is in iOS 7 versions.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18878259/1083859

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if ([YourTableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
            [YourTableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
        }
```

Comment: Why do I need to set the inset to 0? I need the inset to be 30. But I just don't need the extra white line only.

Answer (score 0):

Please set the seperatorinset for table view to zero.[image]